# Yii2 deleting records

Tags: mysql, yii2

I'm trying to delete records in Yii2 using folowing code:

```
$query = "DELETE `master_contacts`
        FROM `master_contacts`
        LEFT JOIN `master_list_contacts`
        ON `master_list_contacts`.`master_contact_id` = `master_contacts`.`id`
        WHERE `master_contacts`.`deleted` = 1
        AND `master_list_contacts`.`id` IS NULL";

    Yii::$app->db->createCommand($query);
```

I have [Following](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c9c96/1) database structure.

Query works perfectly in mysql client but I can't get it work in yii (although I didn't get any error).

Could someone tell me please how I supposed do this in yii?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use pure SQL you should call `execute` method:

```
$query = "DELETE `master_contacts`
    FROM `master_contacts`
    LEFT JOIN `master_list_contacts`
    ON `master_list_contacts`.`master_contact_id` = `master_contacts`.`id`
    WHERE `master_contacts`.`deleted` = 1
    AND `master_list_contacts`.`id` IS NULL";

Yii::$app->db->createCommand($query)->execute();
```